# How to stop previously song in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to develop a audio player using JavaFX. So, till now, my audio player has these basic functions - open, play, pause, stop, volume slider and seeking bar.
Here is the problem, When I run the application and open any song, it starts to play. But when I open any other using(Using FileChooser and in the background, previous song is still playing) it also starts to play along with previous song(it was continuously playing). So, How do I this- When I play new song, the previous one stops. Here is my FXMLController code:

```
 public void open(ActionEvent e){


    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(selectedFile != null){

    String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

    path = path.replace("\\","/");
    me = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
    mp = new MediaPlayer(me);
    mv.setMediaPlayer(mp);
    musicBox.setText(path); 
    volumeSlider.setValue(0.7 * 100);
    volumeSlider.valueProperty().addListener((Observable observable) -> {
    mp.setVolume(volumeSlider.getValue()/100);
    });

    mp.currentTimeProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) -> {
        seekSlider.setValue(newValue.toSeconds());
    });

    seekSlider.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
        mp.seek(Duration.seconds(seekSlider.getValue()));
    });

    mp.play();

    }
}
public void play(ActionEvent e){
mp.play();
}

public void pause(ActionEvent e){
mp.pause();
}

public void stop(ActionEvent e){
mp.stop();
}


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stop the previous audio, like

```
if(selectedFile != null){
    String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
    if(mp!=null) mp.stop();
    //rest of code
```

Comment: Probably needs a null check on `mp`, for the case of the first selection.

Comment: @James_D Thanks. I've taken that in account now.

Comment: Thank you so much! @FrankUnderwood :D It worked!
Will ask some more questions about this project :P